# Cursor position maintain by arrow keys

Tags: gridview

Im using Dynamic Gridview with textboxes

If i select any row of the textbox then cursor will maintain on that place..

Suppose if i use Arrow keys (left ,right,up,down) and i have to move cursor on each record as per the key direction

how? is any javascrript for this senario?

Comment: Dynamic Gridview is a pure Java script component ? an ASP.net component ? JSF component ?